# More efficient way to get the ONLY element with a certain css class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a menu with several **linkbuttons** `<a class="selected">`. When I click on one I apply a class `selected`, when I click to another one I have to remove its class and assing this class to the new clicked linkbutton.

Therefore there are only one element with a certain class name **at the same time** and I want to select it in order to remove this class.

I know:

`$('.myclass').removeClass('myclass');`

I think is not efficient because it has to check all elements of DOM

Which is the more efficient way to get this element: `<a class="selected">` and remove its class `selected`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't check all elements : it uses the optimized [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) function.

So looking for elements by their classes, even if not as fast than looking by id, is fast enough, both using jQuery or Vanilla JS.

This being said, as there is only one element (and supposing your element doesn't have other classes), you can avoid the parsing made by jQuery if it's really so important for you to make it faster :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].className = '';
```

---

For people wanting to see the [code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), this is one of the possible "speed-ups" in jQuery searches for element :

```
// Speed-up: Sizzle(".CLASS")
} else if ( (m = match[3]) && assertUsableClassName && context.getElementsByClassName ) {
    push.apply( results, slice.call(context.getElementsByClassName( m ), 0) );
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I forgot the `' '`. Edited.

Comment: So internally jQuery uses this `getElementsByClassName` when you do `$('classname')`? But how can he know that there are only 1 element?

Comment: He doesn't know but the browsers internally maintain a kind of map of elements by their classes. So it's fast to directly get them without iterating over all elements.

Comment: What about `$(container).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');` ?

Comment: @a_maar When you can restrain the search, it's generally better. But when you're using a fast search (on id or tag or classe) and there is very few matches, a global search is sometimes faster. But I don't get why you're trying to optimize that : this is a fast operation and it's unlikely you have performance problems here.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a more efficient way to do that; if it only has a class, and not an ID that you could store, then your best option **is** the class selector.